# In-app sms sending in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, adobe, air-native-extension

How to send sms within an iphone and android app using as3. I found this code while googling:

```
var callURL:String="sms:0-123-456-7890";
var targetURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest(callURL);
navigateToURL(targetURL);
```

Its working, but it is navigating the app to sms window controller. Can it be done without opening the sms controller window. Is there anything that opens a window within the app itself. Is there any air native extenson which perform this for android and iphone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, using navigateToURL is going to pop you over to the phones default SMS app. To get around this you're going to need to use a native extension.

I know of one for [Android](http://www.smallscreendesign.com/2011/09/29/air-native-extensions-rock/):

https://github.com/mr-archano/Android-AIR-Extensions

If you have an Android phone you can check out a demo of this ANE inside of the [AIRexplorer](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=AIRExplorer) app. Select the SMS ANE version from the list (the app includes an extension as well as navigateToURL)

I don't know of one for iOS right now so you may have to do a little bit of digging

Oh Also, wanted to add a comment because I'm not really sure of your intent here.

If your goal is to send a sms without **any** user interaction that is not going to be possible. ANE or not

Comment: Is it possible to send sms in ios with user interaction. but adding a body to sms through code????

Comment: There is a Objective C solution, if someone could make a native extension of that it would be great! I don't have the skill unfortunately. http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/iphone-tutorial-how-to-send-in-app-sms/

Answer (score 0):

I very much doubt that either ios or android (maybe if you root your device?) would allow sending a SMS without the users explicit consent.

Comment: I want to open the sms window within the app. So, that we can return from the window to our app.